# Suggestions regarding the .NET tool to use for project

Tags: .net, asp.net, winforms, adrotator, ticker

I need to develop a project that needs to have a Ticker and an AdRotator, apart from some button controls and a banner.

I have two options - ASP.NET and Windows Forms.

With Windows Forms, I've been able to develop the Ticker, but I don't know how to develop the AdRotator.

With ASP.NET, I'll have to develop Ticker using AJAX, whereas the AdRotator is already present.

The software is to be used as a standalone. I'm thinking of using Windows Forms for the development so that the requirements for the end-user is only the .NET Framework and not ths IIS plus the deployment would be easier. What should I use for the development?

If you suggest Windows Forms, please throw some light for the development of AdRotator.

Note: 
I don't have any knowledge on AJAX and I don't have much time for the development. Is it possible to develop the Ticker using some other technology other than AJAX ?

Comment: As I said, it is to be used as a standalone application. Moreover, even I have Windows Forms in mind but I've no idea on how to do the advertisement control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The software is to be used as a
>   standalone. I'm thinking of using
>   Windows Forms for the development so
>   that the requirements for the end-user
>   is only the .NET Framework and not ths
>   IIS

If you use ASP.NET the only thing the user will need is a *browser*, which everyone already has. If you go with Windows Forms, how will you distribute and update the application?

> Note: I don't have any knowledge on AJAX and I don't have much time for
>   the development. Is it possible to
>   develop the Ticker using some other
>   technology other than AJAX ?

You could always use javascript to refresh the page at regular intervals, although it may not be the most pleasant of user experiences.

Based on the requirements you have described, I think a web based solution will be more than capable of providing a good user experience.

If you do decide to go with ASP.NET (or any other web framework) you will want to check out [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/). If you haven't used these frameworks before they may take a litte getting used to, but if you are a proficient programmer it should be fairly easy, and once you know how to use them, writing a ticker and an ad rotator will be trivial.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'm quite satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused...asp.net is for the web, windows forms is for client (ie desktop).  Which one you choose should be based which environment you intend to deploy to.

You also mention a banner, which leads me to believe it is almost certainly a web based project, so you should use asp.net

Comment: I'm not sure whether the banner would actually be put or not. Please don't concentrate on the banner thing. The point to be noted is that it would be run on a single computer. No intranet/internet would be required.

Answer (score 0):

For the ticker control in ASP.NET you should check out the ASP.NET control gallery. Also, ticker control should not be that difficult to implement. Check out the following link:

[link text](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=177)